# uiviewcontroller not getting import from parent class in ios

Tags: ios, inheritance, uiviewcontroller

I have the following parent class:

```
//GAViewController.h
@interface GAViewController : UIViewController

@end

//GAViewController.m
#import "GAViewController.h"
#import "GAConfigs.h"

@interface GAViewController ()

@end

@implementation GAViewController

@end
```

And I have the following child class which implements the parent like this:

```
// GARegisterLoginViewController.h
#import "GAViewController.h"

@interface GARegisterLoginViewController : GAViewController

@end


//GARegisterLoginViewController.m
#import "GARegisterLoginViewController.h"

@interface GARegisterLoginViewController ()

@end

@implementation GARegisterLoginViewController
// I cannot reference GAConfigs.h in the methods here
@end
```

My `configs` file is like this:

```
#ifndef GAConfigs_h
#define GAConfigs_h

//Segues
#define LOGINREGISTER_TO_REGISTER_SEGUE @"loginregisterToRegisterSegue"
#define LOGINREGISTER_TO_LOGIN_SEGUE @"loginregisterToLoginSegue"

#endif
```

The problem is in `GARegisterLoginViewController.m`. I cannot reference `GAConfigs` in the child class even though it is imported in the parent class.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are importing the file inside of your implementation file (`.m`).

If you move the file to your header file (`.h`), it will be inherited properly.